# How to properly show the Excerpt only if it exists?

Tags: excerpt

I have the following two functions in my theme:

```
function content($limit) {
     global $post;
      $content = explode(' ', get_the_content(), $limit);
      if (count($content)>=$limit) {
        array_pop($content);
        $content = implode(" ",$content);
$content = wp_strip_all_tags($content, true);
      } else {
        $content = implode(" ",$content);
      } 
      $content = preg_replace('/\[.+\]/','', $content);
      $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content); 
      $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
      return $content;
    }

function contentnoimg($limit) {
     global $post;
      $content = explode(' ', get_the_content(), $limit);
      if (count($content)>=$limit) {
        array_pop($content);
        $content = implode(" ",$content);
$content = wp_strip_all_tags($content, true);
      } else {
        $content = implode(" ",$content);
      }   
      $content = preg_replace('/(<img.+?>)/','', $content);
      $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content); 
      $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
      return $content;
    }
```

And in the loop, it is called this way:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array('class'=>'post_thumbnail_common', 'alt' => get_the_title() , 'title' => get_the_title(), 'itemprop'=>'image' ));
echo contentnoimg(41);} else { echo content(41); } ?>
```

I would like the site to show `the_excerpt();` only if it exists. If `has_excerpt()` is negative, then it should work as it is right now showing the content of `get_the_content()`

How should the code look like? I tried different ways, but my site stops working, so I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Have you tried `if( has_excerpt() ) { the_excertp(); }`? It seems you know those functions but I don't understand where do you have the problem to implement them.

Comment: I have tried. I know what those functions do, and I have used them in other themes. But in this case I have no idea, whether I should use it in the function, or where the function is called. And I tried both, but I am sure I am disrupting php syntax. Not sure where I should put them and how.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19935351/how-to-detect-if-manual-excerpt-exists-in-wordpress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works.  You probably just had a syntax error.

```
function content( $limit ) {
    global $post;

    if( has_excerpt() ){
        $content = the_excerpt();
    } else {
      $content = explode( ' ', get_the_content(), $limit );
      if ( count($content) >= $limit ) {
        array_pop( $content );
        $content = implode( " ", $content );
        $content = wp_strip_all_tags( $content, true );
      } else {
        $content = implode( " ", $content );
      }

      $content = preg_replace( '/\[.+\]/','', $content );
      $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content ); 
      $content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content );
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: I see you added some spaces, for example here `>= $limit` and here `( ' ',` are the spaces ok, or they are not relevant in the syntax?

Comment: I didn't add any spaces inside empty strings like `( ' ',` but I did add some spacing.  It's just a mixture of preference and WordPress PHP coding standards and doesn't really affect anything besides readability.

Comment: My answer probably doesn't follow this strictly, but it's always good to know the standards the core team is using.  https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/

Comment: strange, now no syntax errors. But the excerpt is not showing up. In the homepage nothing changed. It's still showing `get_the_content()`. But I did add to few posts a manual excerpt in the apposite field. Any idea?

Comment: sorry, it works. I just had to apply the same to the $contentnoimg function :) thanks